# is it possible to run a external web application in iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

Is it possible to run a external web application in iframe?

For example, I have below `iframe` in my application.

```
 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

It loads the url on load but when I click on any of the link it redirects to that link, leaving the iframe. Instead I want to load that redirected page in that iframe only.

Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Thank you.

Comment: remove the target attribute from source links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell you frankly, it is completely dependent on the external website. For the example you provided - `w3schools.com`, all the hyperlinks have an attribute `target="_top"` which forces the webpages to open on the parent most window. I guess you really cannot control it.

Comment: If I am loading some other `url` which does not include `target="_top"` then how to handle it.

Comment: They should work pretty fine within your iframe. You need not do anything. Which is the source you are trying?

Comment: Yes it is working, I tried with `http://www.w3schools.com` so it was not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in head tag in your webpage.

```
<base target="_parent" />
```